# pandas - indexing dataframe by another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes example data:

```
created_at             PM 2.5  PM 10     entry_id
2018-06-13 16:11:43    4.67   5.17        20
2018-06-14 11:16:43    5.01   8.05        21


                          action       end_at
done_at
2018-06-13 10:15:00  action 1           Nan
2018-06-11 12:15:00  action 2           Nan
```

I want to add the "PM 10" Value to the second frame in dependence of the closest time from the first dataframe. The the new dataframe should look like

```
                          action       end_at   PM 10
done_at
2018-06-13 10:15:00  action 1           Nan      5.17
2018-06-11 12:15:00  action 2           Nan      5.17
```

The Problem is that the times doesen't matching each other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) for this, with `direction='nearest'`. From the formatting of your example dataframe, I'm assuming `done_at` is the index, so you'll have to reset the index first:

## Setup:

```
>>> df1
           created_at  PM 2.5  PM 10  entry_id
0 2018-06-13 16:11:43    4.67   5.17        20
1 2018-06-14 11:16:43    5.01   8.05        21
>>> df2
                       action end_at
done_at                             
2018-06-13 10:15:00  action 1    Nan
2018-06-11 12:15:00  action 2    Nan

df1['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['created_at'])

df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

## Merging:

```
new_df = (pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index().sort_values('done_at'),
              df1[['created_at','PM 10']],left_on='done_at',
              right_on='created_at', direction='nearest')
          .drop('created_at',axis=1))

>>> new_df
              done_at    action end_at  PM 10
0 2018-06-11 12:15:00  action 2    Nan   5.17
1 2018-06-13 10:15:00  action 1    Nan   5.17
```

Comment: i get the error "right sight must be sorted". i change df1[['created_at','PM 10']] to df1.sort_values(['created_at','PM 10']) than it works! Thank you verry much!!